# name ImageList is not defined in kaggle website

Tags: python, kaggle, fast-ai

I was practicing some project from Kaggle notebook which is machine learning related code. and i am facing problem at one part. the error is NameError: name 'ImageList' is not defined. the Kaggle notebook link is [this](https://www.kaggle.com/qitvision/a-complete-ml-pipeline-fast-ai) and the cell link is [this](https://www.kaggle.com/qitvision/a-complete-ml-pipeline-fast-ai?scriptVersionId=11220630&cellId=27). How can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error even after defining the ImageList, Run the default first cell in the kaggle or make sure that U have run all the cells.
Even I faced the same issue during my initial practice on kaggle.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).